# what does [ 0 : training_data_len , : ] meant here

Tags: python

what does, `train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len  , : ]` in python

does it mean from 0 to training data length and then up to end

I tried to use it on Jupiter notebook

it is a code from machine learning problem

Comment: They are two separate slices `0:training_data_len` and `:`. What it means depends on the type of `scaled_data`.

Comment: It's 2 dimensional.  dim1 = 0:training_data_len  ,  dim2 = all.

Comment: so it is a 2 D array?

Comment: You're selecting first part of an array - training data. And yes, it's a 2D array. You can check it with `scaled_data.shape` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to select rows starting from zero till training_data_len and all the columns from your scaled_data.